# Get the most used combination of words on social networks

Tags: api, twitter, nlp

I want to know if there is a way ( an **API** or an online **tool**) that gives for an entred word a list of most used together words on twitter or any social media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume of tweets is so large that to get a 100% accurate reading would be computationally expensive and impractical. That said, Twitter does have a [Sample Stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/sample-realtime/api-reference/get-statuses-sample), which is a random real-time sampling of tweets. My assumption is that might approximate what's happening in real-time and you could measure words that occur in a specific time frame.

If you were looking for words coinciding with another word, you could also use the [Filter Stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter). e.g. Filter on "trump" to get all the associated words. Additionally, you use the [Search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview) on "trump", though those results will only go back 2 weeks and aren't comprehensive.

Comment: thank you for your answer, what I really need is, for example, having the word "trump" what are the words that are usually written in the same tweet with the word "trump"

Comment: Answer updated - hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: could you please give me a short example of how to use the filter stream I was mining the documentation and still didn't get how to use the filter by keywords and thank you in advance   :)

Comment: @mina I don't know what language or library you're using and it would help to see a small sample of what you've tried so far. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help to learn how to ask a good question. Also, you can visit https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries to see what libraries are available. I wrote LINQ to Twitter, but don't know if you're using C# or some other language.

Comment: I'm using python as language and tweepy as twitter API